# Hypernyms for "reactants" and "products"?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, hypernyms

I’m looking for a hypernym of both *reactant* and *product*.

That is, I want to be able to say that both reactants and products are <*unknown term*>, but I don’t know what term applies to both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reactants and products are both *chemicals*, or *substances*, or *chemical substances*.

No idea why this could possibly be tagged "programming", though.

Comment: It's for an app I'm making, but that is pretty irrelevant. Thanks for your edits, by the way. A hypernym is a word I've definitely thought of a lot but never known.

Comment: I'm not sure about terminology here. The set {reactants, products} probably isn't identical to {substances} but to a subset of the latter (though admittedly, even helium isn't inert).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I'm also not sure about it. I ended up using chemical though.